# I tried to make a settings page but when i click on settings button to navigate to that page ,the following above error is appearing on console

Tags: angular

```
 Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken ToastConfig]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[InjectionToken ToastConfig]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken ToastConfig!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken ToastConfig]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[InjectionToken ToastConfig]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken ToastConfig!
    at NullInjector.get (core.js:778)
    at resolveToken (core.js:2564)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:2490)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:2353)
    at resolveToken (core.js:2564)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:2490)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:2353)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:26403)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:27491)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:657)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
    at zone-evergreen.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:34182)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:469)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1603)
```

I tried to make a settings page but when I click on settings button to navigate to that page, the following above error is appearing on console. Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you provide some code from your router and module? It's an error related to dependency injection, there may be some imports or configuration you've missed

Answer (score 2):

Your error is linked to the NgxToastr lib, the config is missing. Did you import the module in your app.module.ts ?

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ToastrModule.forRoot() // ToastrModule added
  ] ...
```

Comment: ThankYou for your answer .The issue has been resolved